# Mysql timeout when amount of request occurs, but most of time the activity connections less than max connections. Why?

Tags: mysql, azure, timeout

There is a bug in my project, some operations will trigger the MySQL timeout exception. After tracking metrics of azure, It's will happen when there were a number of connections produced. 
[image]

The red arrow represent the timeout exception that occurs time.

In the first arrow, There is a Too Many Connections Exception and lot of Timeout exceptions following it. It's match expectations, but the others throw timeout exception directly, I can not find the reason.

I think the wave peak will cause the exception, but without solid evidence

My azure MySQL max-connections is 60. So what is the reason for MySQL timeout when activity connections less than 60?

Thanks in advance.

exceptions:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Connect Timeout expired.
 ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.BeginConnect(IPAddress address, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.ConnectAsync(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 871
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.OpenTcpSocketAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line 338
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 143
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line 143
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 670
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 332
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.ExecuteWithReturnValueAsync[T](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Ic.Account.AppUserManager.GetAppUserAsync(Guid id) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Abp.CustomModules/modules/IC.Account/src/IC.Account.Domain/AppUserManager.cs:line 108
   at Ic.Account.Account.UserManagerAppService.GetAsync(Guid id) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Abp.CustomModules/modules/IC.Account/src/IC.Account.Application/Account/UserManagerAppService.cs:line 95
   at Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.ExecuteWithReturnValueAsync[T](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Auditing.AuditingInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.ExecuteWithReturnValueAsync[T](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Authorization.AuthorizationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.ExecuteWithReturnValueAsync[T](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
   at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.ExecuteWithReturnValueAsync[T](IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

Comment: The client connect timeout and max connections are not directly linked. Client connect timeout means that the client tried to connect mysql, but got no response within the configured timeout period. Max connection error means that the client did manage to communicate with mysql server, but the server rejected the connection. Probably your network bandwidth is not enough or the mysql server is busy serving the existing connections / queries and does not have the resources to deal with a new connection request. You need to investigate to determine the exact root cause.

Comment: Yes, I lookup network in/out, CPU, and other metrics can not find some unusual.